# How to save the response of Azure Data Factory's Web Activity (Bulk API) as a csv file in blob storage?

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

I have a Web activity that loads data into Salesforce using Bulk API and gets the response back for the failed records. I want to save the failed response as a csv file in the blob storage. I have tried to use another Web activity and copy activity but nothing seems to work. Any tips on how the response can be converted to csv file and stored in the blob storage?

Below is Response from Web Activity

[image]

This is the Web Activity where I am trying to get the response in the body
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this link if it helps
Last web activity put one more webactivity.
In the web activity body put @activity('Web1').output
or
@activity('Web1').output.data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/129351/azure-data-factory-web-activity-save-output.html

URL -- you will get from the storage account property section
https://azadlsgen2eim.blob.core.windows.net/

Try one if it works I am not sure on extension.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article Anuj, this is exactly what worked for me.